# Split list of lists in new list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists A_str that contains information about company names and financial ratios.
Now I would like to have one new list only with the company names and a second list with all the ratios.
So far I could split the list at the '-' but I can't append these new elements to the new lists 'company' and 'ratios'.

```
A_str = ['Name',
         'AMAZON.COM - TOT RETURN IND',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - NET CASH FLOW - FINANCING',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - NET CASH FLOW - INVESTING',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - NET CASH FLOW-OPERATING ACTIVS',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - COST OF GOODS SOLD (EXCL DEP)',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - EARNINGS BEF INTEREST & TAXES',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - EBIT & DEPRECIATION',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - GROSS INCOME',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - NET SALES OR REVENUES',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - OPERATING INCOME',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - NET INCOME AVAILABLE TO COMMON',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - ACCOUNTS PAYABLE',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - CASH',
         "AMAZON.COM INC - COMMON SHAREHOLDERS' EQUITY",
         'AMAZON.COM INC - CURRENT ASSETS - TOTAL',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - CURRENT LIABILITIES-TOTAL',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - TOTAL INVENTORIES',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - LONG TERM DEBT',
         'AMAZON.COM INC - TOTAL ASSETS']

    for element in A_str:
        company.append(element.split('-'))
    print company
```

Output should look like this:

```
company = [AMAZON.COM, AMAZON.COM INC, AMAZON.COM INC... AMATON.COM INC]
ratios = [TOT RETURN IND, NET CASH FLOW - FINANCING, NET CASH FLOW - INVESTING... TOTAL ASSETS]
```

Comment: Doesn't look like list of lists

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply map the split, filter if it makes a size 2 tuple, and zip it to get the values separately:

```
In[9]: l=['Name', 'AMAZON.COM - TOT RETURN IND', 'AMAZON.COM INC - NET CASH FLOW - FINANCING', 'AMAZON.COM INC - NET CASH FLOW - INVESTING', 'AMAZON.COM INC - NET CASH FLOW-OPERATING ACTIVS', 'AMAZON.COM INC - COST OF GOODS SOLD (EXCL DEP)', 'AMAZON.COM INC - EARNINGS BEF INTEREST & TAXES', 'AMAZON.COM INC - EBIT & DEPRECIATION', 'AMAZON.COM INC - GROSS INCOME', 'AMAZON.COM INC - NET SALES OR REVENUES', 'AMAZON.COM INC - OPERATING INCOME', 'AMAZON.COM INC - NET INCOME AVAILABLE TO COMMON', 'AMAZON.COM INC - ACCOUNTS PAYABLE', 'AMAZON.COM INC - CASH', "AMAZON.COM INC - COMMON SHAREHOLDERS' EQUITY", 'AMAZON.COM INC - CURRENT ASSETS - TOTAL', 'AMAZON.COM INC - CURRENT LIABILITIES-TOTAL', 'AMAZON.COM INC - TOTAL INVENTORIES', 'AMAZON.COM INC - LONG TERM DEBT', 'AMAZON.COM INC - TOTAL ASSETS']

In[22]: companies, ratios =zip(*filter( lambda y: len(y) == 2, map(lambda x: tuple(x.split(" - ")), l)))
In[23]: companies
Out[22]: 
('AMAZON.COM',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC',
 'AMAZON.COM INC')
In[24]: ratios
Out[23]: 
('TOT RETURN IND',
 'NET CASH FLOW-OPERATING ACTIVS',
 'COST OF GOODS SOLD (EXCL DEP)',
 'EARNINGS BEF INTEREST & TAXES',
 'EBIT & DEPRECIATION',
 'GROSS INCOME',
 'NET SALES OR REVENUES',
 'OPERATING INCOME',
 'NET INCOME AVAILABLE TO COMMON',
 'ACCOUNTS PAYABLE',
 'CASH',
 "COMMON SHAREHOLDERS' EQUITY",
 'CURRENT LIABILITIES-TOTAL',
 'TOTAL INVENTORIES',
 'LONG TERM DEBT',
 'TOTAL ASSETS')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer, worked out perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Split each item and zip the result, omitting the header element:

```
company, ratios = zip(*(item.split(' - ') for item in A_str[1:]))
```

If you're okay with mutating `A_str`, you can pop the header element instead:

```
A_str.pop(0)
company, ratios = zip(*(item.split(' - ') for item in A_str))
```